# Trouble installing Flask

Tags: software-installation, flask

I'm getting errors while installing Flask. Inside Sublime text editor I'm getting a no Flask installed error, so I tried to install it into Ubuntu, and I'm having trouble there too.

Ubuntu error:

[image: Ubuntu Error]

Sublime error:

[image: Sublime Error]

Comment: You almost got it right. You typed `apt install` then `sudo install` but not what you should have `sudo apt install`...

Comment: Hopefully popey’s comment will sort it for you. Please note - it’s much easier for us to help if you paste text in rather than post screenshots. Thank you!

Comment: Hi Peter, why is it that text is more helpful?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `sudo apt install python3-venv`

Check this https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-flask-on-ubuntu-20-04/

Comment: definitely helpful, thank you.

Comment: you're welcome @cto_evan